# How to detect last visible column in responsive state of Datatables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I want to detect last visible column in responsive `Datatables`. My target is to add border-right on hover state of each row.

As `last-child` doesn't work, I've tried CSS selector `tr:hover td:visible:last`, but it's not working.

Is there any solution where I can get visible columns and add `class` on visible `TD`? So I can apply CSS using `:last-of-type`

[image]

Comment: You want to match the last cell _before_ the hidden one, or all visible cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect Window resize, and DOM change events using domsubtreemodified and window resize event. You can't do this using pure css, as you can not combine :not and :style[] selector together

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('td:visible:last').css('color', 'red');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td:visible:last').css('color', 'red');
});
$('table , table td').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  $('td').css('color', 'black');
  $('td:visible:last').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<td>Home1</td>
<td>Home2</td>
<td>Home3</td>
<td style="display:none">Home4</td>
<td style="display:none">Home5</td>
<td style="display:none">Home6</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yes it will work but how to detect change event? like it will not work if new column is added/removed in hidden list... also change in screen resolution. so I need change event of responsive (I think responsive.recalc() but dont know how it will run automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I have solution but this is not native, so I'll not prefer but I'm using until I get proper solution.

```js
function getLastVisibleColumn(){
  $('table tr td').removeClass('lastVisibleChild');
  $('table tr').each(function(){
   $(this).find('td:visible:last').addClass('lastVisibleChild');
  });
}
$(window).resize(function(){
  getLastVisibleColumn();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  getLastVisibleColumn();
});
```

```css
.lastVisibleChild {
  background: #9F9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td style="display:none">Text</td>
      <td style="display:none">Text</td>
      <td style="display:none">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td style="display:none">Text</td>
      <td style="display:none">Text</td>
      <td style="display:none">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td style="display:none">Text</td>
      <td style="display:none">Text</td>
      <td style="display:none">Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```